# Newly created JSS react app does not start and show blank page

Tags: jss, react

The newly created JSS react app does not start. It shows completely blank page and shows error in the console while accessing the public URL i.e. http://jssreactweb/, Using fresh install of Sitecore 9.1.

> Access to fetch at 'http://jss.sc/sitecore/api/jss/dictionary/JssReactWeb/en?sc_apikey={867CBF59-08E5-4B74-A106-A34485DB1D92}' from origin 'http://jssreactweb' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Here is the console log.

[image: JSS Issue]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing you need to do is to check if the CORS Origins in your API key is not empty and should allow something, you can use `*` for allowing all.

[image]

Secondly, while accessing the public URL i.e. `http://jssreactweb/` *(may be different depending on your installation and configurations)*
You need to publish this API key. *(It will be nice if you publish the whole website.)*

Answer (score 0):

For me, the app already existed and was working fine. After some deployments, the app started showing plain white page without any error. I found that the JSS files in my local Sitecore instance got corrupted. I reinstalled JSS package and it fixed the issue.